# Is it possible to send a customer to the beginning of the journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I've an email activity and an bounce engagement activity on a journey. On the "no" path for the bounce, I've a decision split to check the stage of an opportunity and, in one of those stages, I want to send the customer to the beginning of the journey to receive the first email again.

I can't do it with the join option but there is some setting on the journey to push the customer back?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the entry event for your journey?

Comment: I'm currently an Audience, but can change it to a Data Extension, if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using the Update Contact activity in your 1st Journey, updating a DE (five fields only) based on your use case.

Create a separate Query/Automation that checks that new DE and sends them through your 2nd Journey.

Answer (score 0):

In your exit criteria you can add the condition based upon stages. Then set the Enter criteria as 'Re-entry after exit'.

Once customer reaches that stage they will automatically exits. Once the entry criteria again satisfies they will come again into the journey.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought about it too, thanks. 

I am thinking this way: since I have an automation running with a query to populate a data extension, there will be an event when the journey starts. After that, is it possible to add another query activity to filter the customers and fire a different journey, just with those filtered customers? 

I will have two different journeys: one for every customer and a new one only for the customers who I needed to send to the beginning of the first one. 

I don't know if it's possible tho.